# How do I determine set and sketch image of function $g(\mathbb{R}^2)$ if $g(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} e^x\cos y\\ e^x\sin y\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: functions

How do I determine set and sketch image of function $g(\mathbb{R}^2)$ if $g(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} e^x\cos y\\ e^x\sin y\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 0):

Write $g(x,y)=(u,v)$ where $u=e^x \cos y$, $v=e^x \sin y$.

Then $u^2+v^2=e^{2x}$

For a fixed $x$, what does this equation represent in $(u,v)$ plane?

the image of $g$ is union of all the locus of $u^2+v^2=e^{2x}$ as $x$ varies over $\mathbb{R}$ - what is that? In particular, pay attention to whether or not $(0,0)$ is in the image.

Comment: Is that circle than? How to represent that as a set?

Comment: as $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$ you get union of all possible circles of radius $r>0$, which is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself except the origin.